# Python/Pandas: Why is float producing an extra space in my data?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I'm trying to work with Pandas/excels and I'm running into an issue.

I have the following negative numbers in excel (this is how its been formatted/I just started a new job and trying to get running despite not knowing much Python).
-It's listed as ($246.00) in the sheet, but shows as -246 in the box above in Excel)

Negative numbers here in Excel
[image: Negative numbers here in Excel]

Now, my code string looks like this in Jupyter notebook for this line:

```
apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',',"").replace('(',"-").replace(')',"").replace('$',"")))
```

But I'm seeing the following error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-  246.00'
[image: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '- 246.00']

Can anybody help me understand how to fix this? I've been drowning in code errors this week that weren't supposed to be happening on my first week.

Comment: How are you reading the data into Python from Excel?  By using xlwings to re-create the problem I don't receive an error (and also don't have one from running your code for one value).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can take currency from an excel and turn it into a negative float

```
data = {
    'Column1' : ['($246.00)']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].replace( '[\$,)]','', regex=True ).replace( '[(]','-',   regex=True ).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a space in the result, replace that out with null. here is the solution

```
apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',',"").replace('(',"-").replace(')',"").replace('$',"").replace(' ',"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apply(lambda x: -float(str(x).replace('($'," ").replace(')',""))
```

This makes the value negative after formatting the string, which is much simpler.